# Store "Provider" and "Terraform" version in separate TF file?

Tags: terraform, provider

Currently, I have to define the Terraform version and Provider version in each of my Terraform templates.

I would like to have a file outside of my Terraform templates where I can define the Provider version and Terraform version to use for every template in the directory structure.

I've looked at using an overrides file (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html), but it appears I'd have to define the whole Terraform/Provider block from each template within the `override.tf` file. I'd really like to just be able to tell Terraform to look at (pseudo-file) `versions.tf`, for example, to get the necessary versions for every template.

So something like this would be the desired (simplified) directory structure:

```
 terraform
     ├── dev
     │   └── main.tf
     ├── prod
     │   └── main.tf
     ├── stg
     │   └── main.tf
     └── versions.tf
```

Right now there would need to be only one Provider version and one Terraform version defined in `versions.tf`

Is it possible to pass Provider/Terraform version into templates in this way?

Comment: Is there any reason why those directories could not be workspaces? That would fix your problem and others.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use [Terraform Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) then create a symlink in each subdirectory pointing to the `versions.tf` file.

For example, if your structure is:

```
terraform
     ├── dev
     │   └── main.tf
     ├── prod
     │   └── main.tf
     ├── stg
     │   └── main.tf
     └── versions.tf
```

And you want each subdirectory (`dev`, `prod`, `stg`) to point to the `versions.tf` file on the root `terraform` directory, create a symlink in each subdirectory:

```
ln -sf terraform/versions.tf terraform/dev/versions.tf
ln -sf terraform/versions.tf terraform/prod/versions.tf
ln -sf terraform/versions.tf terraform/stg/versions.tf
```

Your final structure would be:

```
terraform
     ├── dev
     │   └── main.tf
     │   └── versions.tf -> ../versions.tf
     ├── prod
     │   └── main.tf
     │   └── versions.tf -> ../versions.tf
     ├── stg
     │   └── main.tf
     │   └── versions.tf -> ../versions.tf
     └── versions.tf
```

Using Terraform Workspaces, instead of having a sub-directory for each "environment" you're using so have a single directory like:

```
terraform
     ├── main.tf
     └── versions.tf
```

And a workspace per environment which you create by doing:

```
terraform workspace new dev
```

You then use terraform interpolation to do something different depending on which environment you are working on, terraform states are also stored separately per workspace.

So if you want to work on the `dev` environment you switch to that one:

```
terraform workspace select dev
```

Comment: I do use workspaces, but not quite sure how that solves this issue. Could you elaborate? Similarly, how could you achieve this with symlinks?

Comment: @xyz1234 I've edited my answer with some more information.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I see what you're saying. So it sounds like I'd have to define my provider blocks, terraform blocks, remote_state blocks for each template in versions.tf, correct?